# NSArray componentsSeperatedByString Sigabrt

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, nsarray, sigabrt

I get a Sigabrt at the NSlog and i have no idea why - any suggestions?

```
NSString* contentList = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:currentFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray* contentArray = [contentList componentsSeparatedByString:@"$$"];

NSLog(@"%@%@",contentList,[contentArray count]);
kunden = [contentArray objectAtIndex:0];
kundenView.text = kunden;
```

Following Joes suggestions, I now got:

```
   NSString* contentList = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:currentFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
NSArray* contentArray = [[contentList componentsSeparatedByString:@"$$"] retain];
if ([contentArray count] > 0) {
    NSLog(@"%@%@",contentList,[contentArray count]);
    kunden = [contentArray objectAtIndex:0];
    kundenView.text = kunden;
}
```

Which gives me an EXC_BAD_ACCESS at the NSLog thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I get a Sigabrt at the NSlog

Your NSLog statement is trying to print an integer as if it was an object:

```
NSLog(@"%@%@",contentList,[contentArray count]);
           ^
         Here!
```

Replace `%@` with `%d`.

You can read more on format specifiers in the [String Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html).

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking to make sure you have at least 1 element in your array. Accessing `[contentArray objectAtIndex:0]` will be an issue if the `contentArray` is empty.

Comment: Updated my question, getting a bad access now.